# Python boto3 library not working on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am booting up an EC2 with Amazon Linux 2 AMI (2.0.20200722.0 x86_64 HVM)

I want to run a python script that uses boto3 library.

Steps taken:

1. Launch AMI
2. Install python3 `sudo yum install python3 -y`
3. Create virtual env `python3 -m venv env`
4. Install boto3 'pip install boto3'
5. Activate env `source env/bin/activate`
6. Create simple boto3 python script (below)
7. Run script, get error (below)

Python code

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client(
    "ec2",
    aws_access_key_id="",
    aws_secret_access_key="",
    region_name="eu-west-1"
)
```

Error

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-28-238 ~]$ python3 copy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 14, in <module>
    import copy
  File "/home/ec2-user/copy.py", line 25, in <module>
    client = boto3.client(
AttributeError: module 'boto3' has no attribute 'client'
```

What am I missing here? I am surprised that amazons out of the box OS does not work with their python library

Comment: You can't name your file `copy.py` because there is a builtin module named "copy"

Comment: Can you just rename `copy.py` to `mycopy.py` for example, and try again.

Comment: How did you install boto3? I don't see it in your 'steps taken' list.

Comment: @jarmod I neglected to add that, I'm going to add that now.

Comment: @jordanm ... wow ...

Comment: well why don't you post that as the answer @jordanm

Comment: It's the [name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap). Less than ideal behavior on the part of Python.